# Catch invalid hibernate connection URL error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, url, connection

If I put the wrong connection URL in my hibernate.cfg.xml file, I want to be able to detect it and terminate gracefully, but I can't figure out how; it just hangs indefinitely on buildSessionFactory() during the hibernate initialisation procedure:

```
SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

It's in a try block, and I'm trying to catch a generic Exception, but buildSessionFactory() never throws one, it just hangs. This is the URL element in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://123.123.123.123/mydb</property>
```

My system: Ubuntu 9.10 with Tomcat 5.5, Java 1.6, Hibernate 3 and MySQL 5.

When I first initialise hibernate, it just hangs for 22 seconds, then starts spitting out warnings about threads and deadlock (starting with this):

```
15:16:25,758  WARN ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.class: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@a010ba -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
15:16:25,761  WARN ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.class: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@a010ba -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Managed Threads: 3
Active Threads: 3
Active Tasks: 
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@109da93 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1ed1dbe (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@3bc1a1 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
Pending Tasks: 
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@12549c4
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@10df4e2
Pool thread stack traces:
Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:215)
    com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:284)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2194)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:723)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

EDIT: here's my c3p0 properties from my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
```

Comment: The delay you're seeing is most likely caused by c3p0's acquireRetryDelay and acquireRetryAttempts properties which will retry the connection after pausing for a short time (default is 1 second).   Overall, it seems silly (unless there's something about your setup I don't understand) to put much effort into making your app handle simple configuration mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my comment on Pascal's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BryanD mentioned in a comment, `buildSessionFactory()` is not really hanging, the time is very likely spent in c3p0 which is trying to reconnect. Quoting the c3p0 [documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html):

> When a c3p0 DataSource attempts and fails to acquire a Connection, it will retry up to `acquireRetryAttempts` times, with a delay of `acquireRetryDelay` between each attempt. If all attempts fail, any clients waiting for Connections from the DataSource will see an Exception, indicating that a Connection could not be acquired. Note that clients do not see any Exception until a full round of attempts fail, which may be some time after the initial Connection attempt. If `acquireRetryAttempts` is set to 0, c3p0 will attempt to acquire new Connections indefinitely, and calls to `getConnection()` may block indefinitely waiting for a successful acquisition.

If you didn't configure it, the default value of the [`acquireRetryAttempts`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#acquireRetryAttempts) is 30 so it may indeed take some time for `buildSessionFactory()` to return. But, unless you used a value less than or equal to zero in which case c3p0 will keep trying to fetch a Connection indefinitely, it will.

Maybe you could use a lower value. Or maybe you could just use the right URL and stop spending time on an exceptional situation (a configuration mistake).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried setting c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=1 (and confirmed it was set with the debug output) but it behaved exactly the same. I only ask about all this because I'm testing my app on a few different servers, and I wasted plenty of time figuring out what was wrong when the app just hung indefinitely when I'd simply forgotten to update the connection URL. I thought there might be a simple fix to catch this error to save myself and others from wasting time debugging configuration mistakes in the future...